# How can i define a global variable to make switch button?

Tags: javascript, html

This is the javascript code i did:

```
var buttonPause = 'Pause Slide';
(function (d, w) {

    // user defines

    var
            swapHours = 0,
            swapMinutes = 0,
            swapSeconds = 5,
            swapTotal = (swapHours * 60 + swapMinutes) * 60 + swapSeconds,
            loopSlideShow = true,
            isPaused = true;

    // some handy helper functions

    function classExists(e, className) {
        return RegExp('(\\s|^)' + className + '(\\s|$)').test(e.className);
    }

    function classAdd(e, className) {
        if (classExists(e, className))
            return false;
        e.className += (e.className ? ' ' : '') + className;
        return true;
    }

    function classRemove(e, className) {
        if (!classExists(e, className))
            return false;
        e.className = e.className.replace(
                new RegExp('(\\s|^)' + className + '(\\s|$)'), ' '
                ).replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
        return true;
    }

    function nodeFirst(e) {
        e = e.firstChild;
        while (e && e.nodeType != 1)
            e = e.nextSibling;
        return e;
    }

    function nodeLast(e) {
        e = e.lastChild;
        while (e && e.nodeType != 1)
            e = e.previousSibling;
        return e;
    }

    function nodeNext(e) {
        while (e = e.nextSibling)
            if (e.nodeType == 1)
                return e;
        return null;
    }

    function nodePrev(e) {
        while (e = e.previousSibling)
            if (e.nodeType == 1)
                return e;
        return null;
    }

    function nodeFlush(e) {
        while (e.firstChild)
            e.removeChild(e.firstChild);
    }

    function nodeReplace(e, newNode) {
        nodeFlush(e);
        e.appendChild(
                typeof newNode == 'object' ? newNode : d.createTextNode(newNode)
                );
    }

    function make(tagName, child, attribs, parent) {
        var e = d.createElement(tagName);
        if (child)
            e.appendChild(
                    typeof child == 'object' ? child : d.createTextNode(child)
                    );
        if (attribs)
            for (var i in attribs)
                e[i] = attribs[i];
        if (parent)
            parent.appendChild(e);
        return e;
    }

    function prevent(e, deselect) {
        e.cancelBubble = true;
        if (e.stopPropagation)
            e.stopPropagation();
        if (e.preventDefault)
            e.preventDefault();
        e.returnValue = false;
        if (deselect) {
            if (w.getSelection)
                w.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
            if (d.selection)
                d.selection.empty();
        }
    }

    function controlEvent(e, handler) {
        handler();
        e = e || window.event;
        prevent(e, true);
    }

    function clockFormat(value) {
        value = String(Math.floor(value));
        while (value.length < 2)
            value = '0' + value;
        return value;
    }

    // slideShow functions

    function showCounter() {
        nodeReplace(slideCounter,
                clockFormat(swapCounter / 3600) + ':' +
                clockFormat((swapCounter / 60) % 60) + ':' +
                clockFormat(swapCounter % 60)
                );
    }

    function resetCounter() {
        swapCounter = swapTotal;
        showCounter();
    }

    function makeSlide(newSlide) {
        classRemove(currentSlide, 'ss_show');
        currentSlide = newSlide;
        classAdd(currentSlide, 'ss_show');
    }

    function nextSlide() {
        resetCounter();
        var newSlide = nodeNext(currentSlide);
        if (newSlide)
            makeSlide(newSlide);
        else if (loopSlideShow)
            makeSlide(firstSlide);
    }

    function prevSlide() {
        resetCounter();
        var newSlide = nodePrev(currentSlide);
        if (newSlide)
            makeSlide(newSlide);
        else if (loopSlideShow)
            makeSlide(lastSlide);
    }

    function slideUpdate() {
        if (swapCounter--)
            showCounter();
        else
            nextSlide();
    }

    function pauseSlide() {
        change();
    }

    function change() // no ';' here
    {
        buttonPause = 'Continue Slide';
    }


    function startSlideShow() {
        resetCounter();
        setInterval(slideUpdate, 1000);
    }

    // slideShow setup

    var
            slideShow = d.getElementById('slideShow'),
            slideCounter = make('div', false, {id: 'slideCounter'}),
            slideControls = make('div', false, {id: 'slideControls'}),
            slidePrev = make('a', 'Previous Slide', {
                onclick: function (e) {
                    controlEvent(e, prevSlide);
                },
                className: 'previous',
                href: '#'
            }, slideControls),
            slideNext = make('a', 'Next Slide', {
                onclick: function (e) {
                    controlEvent(e, nextSlide);
                },
                className: 'next',
                href: '#'
            }, slideControls),
            slidePause = make('a', buttonPause, {
                onclick: function (e) {
                    controlEvent(e, pauseSlide);
                },
                className: 'pause',
                href: '#'
            }, slideControls),
            firstSlide = nodeFirst(slideShow),
            lastSlide = nodeLast(slideShow),
            currentSlide = firstSlide,
            swapCounter;
    slideShow.parentNode.insertBefore(slideCounter, slideShow);
    slideShow.parentNode.insertBefore(slideControls, slideShow.nextSibling);

    classAdd(slideShow, 'ss_scripted');
    classAdd(currentSlide, 'ss_show');

    // wait for onload to actually start the countdown

    if (w.addEventListener)
        w.addEventListener('load', startSlideShow, false);
    else
        w.attachEvent('onload', startSlideShow);


})(document, window);
```

[Slide Show](http://jsfiddle.net/7q7zfcmf/)

what i want to do is in the javascript code i added a new button.

Pause Slide.

I also tried to add a global variable out of the main function since if the variable is inisde the function where i declare all the variables the variable have the same value all the time same text 'Pause Slide'

But when i declare the varuiable out of the main function it's colored in purple like the variable not exist.

Then in the javascript code i added two new functions: pauseSlide() and change()

And i'm using the variable buttonPause inside the // slideShow setup slidePause = make...

What  iwant to do is:

When i click the button Pause Slide it will change the button text to Continue Slide and also will pause the timer.
And when i click on it once again it will change the text back to Pause Slide and will continue the timer.

How can i do it the switch button to work ?

Comment: can you remove all the "handy helper" code from your question? It doesn't contribute to the question at hand, and just means we have to scroll lots to even get to any real code.

Comment: you do realize you are creating a local variable `buttonPause` in your `change` function, as such your global variable will not be changed. Remove the `var` keyword

Comment: Why do you pass `d` and `w` into `(function (d, w) {`?